# How to install and open SpriteBuilder ?

Tags: spritebuilder

I am from Hong Kong and I have some problems when I was trying to install SpriteBuilder. SpriteBuilder cannot be found in Hong Kong's App Store,so I need to install it from Github. With zero Github experience, I try to follow the instructions from the file, README.md , to install SpriteBuilder.

What do I need to do to open SpriteBuilder after input these code

```
git clone https://github.com/apportable/SpriteBuilder
cd SpriteBuilder
git submodule update --init --recursive
cd scripts
./build_distribution.py --version 1.x
```

and wait until it finish the install ?

Thanks a lot and I will be extremely grateful if anyone can help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

As SpriteBuilder is no longer available at any store, there is a link to the last 1.4.9 installation:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8kf5zfeg5haaeb1/SpriteBuilder-1.4.9.zip?dl=0

This is by far the best tool for 2d games development imo, even with 2 years without updates (or maybe is because that jeje)

Comment: What happened to this thing. The website is utterly perplexing and possibly just a content farm (Seriously, the thing seems..... drunk)